# Destroy link on many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, destroy

In rails version 3.2.13 I have the following many-to-many relationship setup

Account model:

```
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
```

User model:

```
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :accounts, :through => :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
```

Membership model:

```
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
```

In the routes.rb I have:

```
scope ":account_id" do
    resources :users
end
```

rake routes command gives me the following:

```
       users GET    /:account_id/users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /:account_id/users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /:account_id/users/new(.:format)      users#new
   edit_user GET    /:account_id/users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET    /:account_id/users/:id(.:format)      users#show
             PUT    /:account_id/users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE /:account_id/users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

The problem: I am able to generate successfully all the links except the "Destroy/Delete" one.

The "Edit" link is setup like this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", :controller => "users", :action=>"edit" , :account_id=>@account.id , :id =>membership.user.id%>
```

I tried to setup the "Delete" link like this but it does not work - it takes me to the "Show" action instead (the generated link is http://www.example.com/20/users/13?method=delete ):

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', :controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy", :method=>'delete', :account_id => @account.id, :id=>membership.user.id %>
```

Also, how can the confirmation message "Are you sure you want to delete?" can be added to the link?

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation message can be added by setting "data-confirm" attribute in the link, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', :controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy", :method=>'delete', :account_id => @account.id, :id=>membership.user.id, "data-confirm"=>"Are you sure you want to delete?" %>
```